# How to dock bookmark tool window in PHP Storm?

Tags: phpstorm, bookmarks

In PHP Storm 8, for some reason my bookmark tool window became undocked, I can access it with `shift F11` but for some reason can't dock it on the left anymore, no matter where I drag it, it doesn't drop into the other windows but continues to float.

How can I dock the bookmark tool window?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This Bookmarks window (accessible via <kbd>Shift + F11</kbd> on Windows) is actually how it looks -- you cannot dock it.

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/bookmarks-dialog.html?search=bookmarks

---

The one tool window that can be docked called **"Favorites"** and it lists all your favourites, bookmarks and breakpoints in one window -- <kbd>Alt + 2</kbd> is a standard key for that on Windows.

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/favorites-tool-window.html

Comment: Perfect, that's what I had before, right, `Alt + 2` works, thanks.